# PyTorch Lightning bug: validation after a single gradient step?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch-lightning

PyTorch Lightning 2.0.1, [documentation pseudo-code](https://lightning.ai/docs/pytorch/stable/common/lightning_module.html) below:

**Current:**
Given that `if should_check_val: val_loop()` inside the `for batch in train_dataloader():` loop,
validation across all validation batches takes place after training on a SINGLE train batch.

**Expected:**
Validation accross all validation batches takes place after training on ALL train batches.
`if should_check_val: val_loop()` should be outside of the `for batch in train_dataloader():` loop.

```py
def train_on_device(model):

    setup("fit")
    configure_optimizers()
    on_fit_start()

    # the sanity check runs here

    on_train_start()
    for epoch in epochs:
        fit_loop() #! CALLS Method Below
    on_train_end()

    on_fit_end()
    teardown("fit")


def fit_loop():
    model.train()
    torch.set_grad_enabled(True)

    on_train_epoch_start()

    for batch in train_dataloader(): # TRAINING Loop
        on_train_batch_start()

        on_before_batch_transfer()
        transfer_batch_to_device()
        on_after_batch_transfer()

        out = training_step()

        on_before_zero_grad()
        optimizer_zero_grad()

        on_before_backward()
        backward()
        on_after_backward()

        on_before_optimizer_step()
        configure_gradient_clipping()
        optimizer_step()

        on_train_batch_end(out, batch, batch_idx)

        if should_check_val: #! 
            val_loop() #! VALIDATION Loop

    on_train_epoch_end()
```

Answer (score 0):

by default, the validation loop starts after the training loop. You can configure it using [val_check_interval](https://lightning.ai/docs/pytorch/stable/common/trainer.html#val-check-interval) flag